# Problem using different versions of Lottie in an Android Project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, lottie

I have been using the latest version of Lottie in my project and everything was fine. until I integrated a module that also uses it inside, but in an older version. The problem is that if i use the old version so that it does not break the operation of the module. My lottie files are not rendering in the rest of the app

```
    +--- cl.toc.LivenessAndroid:sdk:1.12.1
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61 -> 1.3.72 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61 (*)
|    +--- io.fotoapparat:fotoapparat:2.7.0
|    |    +--- io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:adapter-rxjava:2.7.0
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.72 (*)
|    |    +--- io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.0
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.72 (*)
|    |    \--- io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:fotoapparat:2.7.0
|    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |         +--- androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.72 (*)
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0 -> 1.3.0 (*)
|    +--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0 -> 3.6.1
|    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.4 -> 2.7.0 (*)
```

This SDK use version 2.7.0 and i use 3.6.1